# Do these matrices have inverses, how to show them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*State whether the following is true or false.*

(1) If $A$ is Hermitian, then $A+iI$ is invertible?

Okay, If A is hermitian then it's eigenvalues are real numbers, couldn't move anywhere from here.

(2) If $Q$ is orthogonal, then $Q+\frac{1}{2}I$ is invertible?

If Q is orthogonal, Q has eigenvalues $1$, $1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ or $-1-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$. The diagonal entries of this matrix is either $\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{3}{2}$ right?. Couldn't move anywhere from here.

(3) If $A$ is real, then $A+iI$ is invertible

Couldn't move a pencil here.

Please help :)

Comment: $\det(A-xId)=0$ iff $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. (indeed, this is the expression of the characteristic polynomial of $A$). This should help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing these kinds of problems, it is important to keep in mind the many equivalent characterizations of an eigenvalue. Namely, let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space, $V$,

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if there exists a (nonzero) $v \in V$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$

By algebraic manipulation, we get that:

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if there exists a (nonzero) $v \in V$ such that $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$

which can be rephrased as:

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $T- \lambda I$ has a nontrivial null space (i.e. there is a vector other than zero in the null space of $T-\lambda I$), or, equivalently, if $T-\lambda I$ is not injective.

Invertibility implies injectivity. So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $T-\lambda I$ is not injective, which means that $T- \lambda I$ is not invertible.

So for your first question, you are correct, Hermitian implies that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are real. This means that $A$ has no complex eigenvalues, which means that $A-iI$ is injective. In finite dimensions, injectivity implies invertibility which means that $A-iI$ is invertible. The statement is true.

For your second question: an orthogonal transformation is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$) and all of its eigenvalues are of (complex) modulus $1$. As $\frac{1}{2}$ does not have modulus 1, $\frac{1}{2}$ is not an eigenvalue of $Q$, and thus (in finite dimensions), $Q-\frac{1}{2}I$ is invertible. The statement is true.

For the third question, I will show you a matrix of all real entries that has $i$ as an eigenvalue, which means that $A-iI$ is not invertible. Consider:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I will leave it to you to show that my example does indeed have $i$ as an eigenvalue, making this statement false.

Comment: Still I wanna ask, there are some zero vectors that corresponds to non-zero eigenvalues, this distorts your proof

Comment: The issue of the zero vector and its classification as an eigenvector or not is not standard among mathematicians. A linear operator always has the property $T(0) = 0$. As such, $T(0) = \lambda * 0  = 0$, for every $\lambda$ in the field. If $0$ is the **only** vector such that $Tv = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$, we don't want to consider $\lambda$ an eigenvalue, because this would mean that all linear operators have all possible eigenvalues (with eigenvector 0), and, for lack of a better term, this would be a pretty stupid definition and make the term "eigenvalue" practically meaningless.

Comment: This is why I stipulate the definition of an eigenvalue as I did, specifying there exists a nonzero vector. If we only specify there exists a vector, then all $\lambda$ would be eigenvalues with eigenvector zero. However, there is something convenient about having zero as an eigenvector, because this makes the set of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ a subspace. So I personally, (and some other mathematicians) define an eigenvector as: Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, a vector $v$ is an eigenvector of the linear transformation $T$ if and only if $Tv = \lambda v$.

Comment: By stipulating that $\lambda$ is already an eigenvalue, we prevent all elements of the field from being eigenvalues with eigenvector $0$, because we already know there exists a nonzero vector such that $Tv = \lambda v$, but we make $0$ an eigenvector for all eigenvalues, because it satisfies the property for all $\lambda$, making the set of all eigenvalues with eigenvalue $\lambda$ a subspace.
Other mathematicians will say that $0$ is never an eigenvector, but $0$ is always included in the eigenspace, making the eigenspace a subspace, but the set of all eigenvectors would not be a subspace.

Comment: But all mathematicians will agree that if $0$ is the only vector such that $Tv = \lambda v$, then $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue. 
These definitions need careful treatment though, and you can always ask if a mathematician is considering $0$ an eigenvector or not (though usually they will talk about the eigenspace, of which $0$ is always a part). As I didn’t even use my definition of eigenvector in my proof, I do not see where there would be any problem with how I treated the zero vector, but if I left room for confusion, please point out a specific instance and I will do my best to explain.